# Maximum value of speed of sound in a medium?

Tags: thermodynamics, waves

I read somewhere that speed of sound in a medium cannot be greater than rms velocity of medium particles. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize the RMS speed of the particles as the typical speed at which one particle is capable of shuttling back and forth between two other particles, and that by bouncing off those particles as it does, the one particle is in some sense communicating the presence of the other particles to each other.

Any wave disturbance in the medium formed by a very large number of those particles is going to propagate itself through it by progressively displacing a small number of those particles along the direction of the wave's travel. Once displaced, those particles then communicate the presence of the wave disturbance to their neighbors as schematically described above.

In this simplified picture, you can see that the inter-particle communication speed then establishes the speed of propagation of the wave. The picture is actually more (thermodynamically) complicated than this, but this is the essence of it.

Comment: But why does the necessary particle velocity have to be rms velocity specifically? Is it because it is maximum among the three velocities?

Comment: no, it is the average. note that in any medium, the particles forming it have a distribution of instantaneous velocities; for a gas I think that distribution is called a Maxwell distribution. the peak value of the distribution is the velocity possessed by most of the particles and this is approximated by taking the RMS average of all the velocities in the distribution.

Comment: The OP's statement is only true for gases which communicate by bumping into one another. In a liquid or a solid the molecules are already "touching" and communicate via the "bond/spring" connecting them.

Comment: @Farcher, you are right of course; I assumed sound waves in a compressible medium.